# MongoDB: Add field to all objects in array, based on other fields on same object?

Tags: mongodb

I am fairly new to MongoDB and cant seem to find a solution to this problem.
I have a database of documents that has this structure:

```
   {
      id: 1 
      elements: [ {elementId: 1, nr1: 1, nr2: 3}, {elementId:2, nr1:5, nr2: 10} ]
   }
```

I am looking for a query that can add a value `nr3` which is for example `nr2/nr1` to all the objects in the `elements` array, so that the resulting document would look like this:

```
  {
      id: 1 
      elements: [ {elementId: 1, nr1: 1, nr2: 3, nr3:3}, {elementId:2, nr1:5, nr2: 10, nr3: 2} ]
   }
```

So I imagine a query along the lines of this:

```
db.collection.updateOne({id:1}, {$set:{"elements.$[].nr3": nr2/nr1}})
```

But I cant find how to get the value of `nr2` and `nr1` of the same object in the array.
I found some similar questions on stackoverflow stating this is not possible, but they were 5+ years old, so I thought maybe they have added support for something like this.

I realize I can achieve this with first querying the document and iterate over the elements-array doing updates along the way, but for the purpose of learning I would love to see if its possible to do this in one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of elements
- divide nr2 with `nr1` using `$divide`
- merge current object and new field `nr3` using `$mergeObjects`

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { id: 1 }, 
  [{
    $set: {
      elements: {
        $map: {
          input: "$elements",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              { nr3: { $divide: ["$$this.nr2", "$$this.nr1"] } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/twtgZKaokPq)

Comment: Thank you!  Alas, I have new fields in my array elements. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.collection.update(
  { id:1},
  { "$set": { "elements.$[elem].nr3":elements.$[elem].nr2/elements.$[elem].nr1} },
  { "multi": true }
);
```

I guess this should work